# React values multiply in a table

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to multiply `{value.item.itemPrice}` and `{value.itemCount}` and assigned to next`<td></td>`..I tried using `{value.item.itemPrice}*{value.itemCount}` but not working.please help me to solve this.I get this values from axios get API call.

```
                 <tbody>
                    {itemList.map((value, key) => (
                        <tr key={key}>
                            <td>{value.itemId}</td>
                            <td>{value.item.itemPrice}</td>
                            <td>{value.itemCount}</td>
                            <td>{value.item.itemPrice}*{value.itemCount}</td>   //not woring this
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td>total here</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Comment: `{value.item.itemPrice * value.itemCount}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `{my_var}` everything that is inside is executed as javascript code and you can do mathematical operations or whatever you need.
This is how your code would be so that it works as you need.

```
<td>{value.item.itemPrice * value.itemCount}</td> // this code is ready
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Your first answer is pretty good!

Answer (score 2):

Bracket `{}` will tell JSX parser that the syntax should be interpreted as javascript and return value to be shown. Did you try ?

```
{value.item.itemPrice * value.itemCount}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try That:

```
<td>{value.item.itemPrice * value.itemCount}</td>
```

you were displaying * as a text because it was outside of the brackets, then it wouldn't multiply